# Discord.js How access to voice channel in voice channels in category?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```
const guild_id, channel_id;

const category = client.guilds.get(guild_id).channels.get(channel_id);
const voice_channels = category.children.find(c => c.type == 'voice');
```

I'm set up this. I'm getting voice channels but i can't delete someone of voice channels in this category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to delete a channel you get?
- Does the bot have permissions?

```
var voice_channels = category.children.find(c => c.type == 'voice');
```

- returns first voice channel

If you want to get every channel, use:

```
var voice_channels = category.children.filter(c => c.type == 'voice');
```

Deleting a channel:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=delete

```
var voice_channels = category.children.filter(c => c.type == 'voice');
//Discord.js version 12 (I believe)
var channels = voice_channels.map(e => client.channels.resolve(e))
channels[1].delete()
//use client.channels.get(e) in older versions
```